# Excel VBA project crashing after compiling

Tags: vba, excel, crash, initialization

I have a large userform in a project that is causing some issues when it is loaded into memory. There isn't anything exotic happening in the `Userform_Initialize` event (just populating combo boxes and setting default properties).
Everything was working just fine a few weeks ago when the userform wasn't as big (measured in KB).  Initially, I thought the workbook was corrupted and proceeded to export every userform, module and class, re-import into a new workbook, and subsequently compiling the project as I've always done.  This did not fix the issue. Interestingly enough, when I put a `Stop` at the top of the initialize event, and step through the code, everything works fine.

**Main Idea**

> This got me thinking that the possible cause of the issue is the fact that the userform is very large, thus the process of loading the userform into memory is taking longer than the typical load. Essentially, the vb editor is continuing to execute the code in the initialize event, attempting to access controls that may not be in memory yet.

I have done some crude analysis to get a pretty good idea of just how large the userform in question is.  The userform was exported and re-imported into a blank workbook. The workbook without the userform was around `30 KB`, and with the userform, the workbook was over `350 KB`, so we can conclude that the userform is around `320 KB`.

It is important to note that I have extensive error handling in my project, however, I'm unable to identify this particular error as it is occurring in the initialize event (Error handling is impossible inside this particular event [Bovey, Professional Excel Development, pg 489]).

**Question :** With the exception of a time delay (e.g. `Application.Wait` or `Sleep` via Windows API), is there another approach to avoid crashing?

**UPDATE**
It turns out that delaying the application didn't work reliably either.  I have actually removed the entire Initialize event to no avail as well.  One thing that I forgot to mention in my original post, was that I was abusing the `Debug -->> Compile VBA Project` feature. See my answer below.

Comment: Have you tried the code in blocks, see what you're issue is, it could be one of the combo's triggers an event that's locking things up possibly.

Comment: do you get an error message, before crash like 438 or it just freezes and dies?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav, yes I have.  I have commented every sub section of code, ran the application, and the program still crashes on the initialize event.

Comment: @cyboashu, No I don't receive any errors, the applications just crashes. When an error occurs in the initialize event, it is a catastrophic error, thus no error message can be returned.

Comment: in standard module, do something like `dim frm as new YourUserForm` and then `frm.show`, see if you get a error message?

Comment: try changing the code to `for each c in me.controls:debug.? c.name:next c` this will also help make sure no typos in the control names

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After dealing with this for quite some time, a colleague of mine simply commented one random line of code (not in the `UserForm_Initialize`, just in some random module), saved the file, and reopened it with no issues. We then discovered that the issue was not in the code, but rather with `Debug -->> Compile VBA Project`. For the most part, I use `Debug -->> Compile VBA Project`, about once every hour as I'm coding. I then save that file and continue developing on that very same compiled file. When it is all said and done, I probably run `Debug -->> Compile VBA Project` about 100 times over the course of two weeks. I then found this comment from Chip Pearson on [this website](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/what-does-compile-vbaproject-do.4009781/):

> VBA code is never stored as the plain text that you type in to the
>   editor. Input is immediately converted to platform- and
>   version-independent byte codes called OpCodes. These OpCodes are
>   converted by the editor to the text you see on the screen. When you
>   compile the project, the compiler translates these OpCodes to
>   platform- and version-specific codes called ExCodes. When you run the
>   code, the runtime reads the ExCodes and executes actual machine code
>   on behalf of the project based on the ExCodes. This whole process is
>   similar in principle to how Java and the Java Virtual Machine work.
>
> If you were to export all your VBA code to text files and then remove
>   all the modules and then re-import the code from the text files back
>   into VBA (which is exactly what Rob Bovey's Code Cleaner does), you'll
>   see a decrease in file size. This is because the ExCodes were purged
>   and have not yet been recreated. Then, if you compile the project, the
>   file size will increase because now it stores the ExCodes in addition
>   to the OpCodes.
>
> You really never need to compile the code. VBA will automatically do
>   it when necessary. However, the Compile command also does syntax
>   checking, which is its only real practical purpose.

And this is from Rob Bovey himself found [here](http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/CodeCleaner.htm) (You will also find Rob Bovey's Code Cleaner at that website):

> During the process of creating VBA programs a lot of junk code builds up in your files. If you don't clean your files periodically you will begin to experience strange problems caused by this extra baggage. Cleaning a project involves exporting the contents of all its VBComponents to text files, deleting the components and then importing the components back from the text files.

I then did just as I did above in the original question.  I exported all modules, re-imported them into a fresh excel workbook, added the relevant libraries, and DID NOT (as I was before) run `Debug -->> Compile VBA Project`. I haven't had any issues since.

Comment: Well, you can't skip the compiling if you want to have your template signed and secured with password...